# Do I correctly calculate HashMap's memory consumption?

Tags: java, hashmap

I try to calculate the memory consumption by HashMap using https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/

Could you check me, please? Am I right?

`HashMap` is a number of `Node` objects.

```
Each node consists of:
object overhead: 16 bytes
    final int hash : 4 bytes
    final K key    : 8 bytes
    V value        : 8 bytes
    Node<K,V> next : 8 bytes
                     36 bytes + padding = 40 bytes
```

`HashMap` by itself includes following fields:

```
object overhead              : 16 bytes
Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet : 8 bytes
final float loadFactor       : 4 bytes
int modCount                 : 4 bytes
int size                     : 4 bytes
Node<K,V>[] table            : 40N bytes (16 bytes of object overhead, 4 bytes for the length, and 4 bytes of padding plus the memory needed to store the values)
int threshold                : 4 bytes
Set<K> keySet                : 8 bytes
Collection<V> values         : 8 bytes
                             : 56 + 40N bytes
```

The question is: do I have to consider the size of `Node` in this calculation?
If yes then the size of HashMap is `56 + 160N` if not then `56 + 40N`

What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: Of course - there is a `Node` object per node! _Plus_ the reference to the `Node` in the array. There is a question about `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` - first, this is obviously larger that 8 bytes; second, it's lazily populated and not required for the `Map`.

Comment: Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> is a reference to another object and a reference to an object typically is a memory address and thus uses 8 bytes of memory (on a 64-bit machine)

Comment: Yes, of course - but the `Set` itself takes memory which you have ignored. I take it from your comment that it was intentional?